# Changing prefab's fields from script (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cube prefab with a Cube script attached. The script has public integer variable that is 3 by default.

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
   public int A = 3;
}
```

In another script I make a reference (by dragging in the inspector) to this prefab. And then I change it's variable to 10:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Cube cube;

    void Start()
    {
        cube.A = 10;
    }
}
```

So the question is: what object have I just changed? It is not the prefab, cause as i see in the Assets folder, prefab's variable stayed the same.

Comment: Interesting question I'll need to look into this before I can answer

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you actually are modifying the prefab during runtime. I set up a quick test to show this. I dragged the `Cube` prefab into the inspector for both the `cubePrefab` and `cubeComponent` fields of `GameManager1`, and I dragged the same `Cube` prefab into the inspector for the `cubePrefab` field of `GameManager2`.

Upon starting the game, `GameManager1` modifies the `Cube` component of the prefab to be 10 instead of 3. It then spawns and instance of the prefab and prints its `A` value, showing it to be 10.

One second later, `GameManager2` spawns an instance of the `Cube` prefab and prints its `A` value which also ends up being 10.

**Cube.cs**

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int A = 3;
}
```

**GameManager1.cs**

```
public class GameManager1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    public Cube cubeComponent;    

    void Start()
    {
        cubeComponent.A = 10;
        GameObject spawnedCube = Instantiate(cubePrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log("A = " + spawnedCube.GetComponent<Cube>().A); //Prints 10
    }
}
```

**GameManager2.cs**

```
public class GameManager2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;

    private void Start()
    {
        Invoke("SpawnCube", 1);
    }

    void SpawnCube()
    {
        GameObject spawnedCube2 = Instantiate(cubePrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log("Cube2 A = " + spawnedCube2.GetComponent<Cube>().A);
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Note: The modification to the prefab only persists during runtime. It will revert to its default values afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. Need to mention though that prefab's field would stay changed only for runtime and would revert back to defaults after we stop the game.

Comment: @AnyaBarsukova Yes that is correct. I added it to the answer.